# List Style not setting to none in IE

Tags: html, css

I have a menu structure where Im using an unordered list for my nav. Problem is in IE it appears as though the list style is not set to none as shown below:

[image]

In Chrome however it looks fine:

[image]

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="tabPrincipale" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                        <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
                            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#tabUtenti" onclick="setFrameSrcTop('UtentiSport','#tabGiochi');"><span>Users</span></a></li>
                            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tabUtentiRete" onclick="setFrameSrcTop('ReteUtenti','#tabRete');"><span>Network</span></a></li>

                        </ul>
                        <div id="tabUtenti" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
                            <div id="tabGiochi" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                                <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
                                    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#tabReport" onclick="setFrameSrc('UtentiSport');"><span>Sport</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tabReport" onclick="setFrameSrc('UtentiCasino');"><span>Casino</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tabReport" onclick="setFrameSrc('UtentiPoker');"><span>Poker 3d</span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tabUtentiRete" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide">
                            <div id="tabRete" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                                <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
                                    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#tabReport" onclick="setFrameSrc('ReteUtenti');"><span>Agents</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tabReport" onclick="setFrameSrc('ReteSport');"><span>Sport</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tabReport" onclick="setFrameSrc('ReteCasino');"><span>Casino</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tabReport" onclick="setFrameSrc('RetePoker');"><span>Poker 3d</span></a></li>


                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-tabs #tabGiochi .ui-tabs-nav, .ui-tabs #tabRete .ui-tabs-nav {
list-style: none;
position: relative;
padding: 0;
height: 35px;
background-color: #B10000;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 0,0% 100%,from(#B10000),to(#490000));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#B10000,#490000);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#B10000,#490000);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#B10000,#490000);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#B10000,#490000);
border-radius: 5px;
width: 1162px;
}
#tabGiochi .ui-widget-header, #tabRete .ui-widget-header {
background: #d2232a;
color: #000000;
font-weight: bold;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
list-style: none;
position: relative;
padding: .6em .2em 0;
}
.ui-widget-header {
border: 0;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight: bold;
height: 22px;
}
```

Also, I cant figure out why it is doing this on the lower menu but the above menu is correct ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to set list-style:none; to the LI Element of your List. Try this:

```
ul.ui-tabs-nav li { list-style:none; }
```

Comment: can you try to set globally the list-style to none to check if it works?

for example  just: ul li { list-style:none !important; }

Just for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Add this class in your CSS

```
.ui-tabs ul, .ui-tabs ul li
{
 list-style:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.ui-tabs ul{
list-style-type:none;
}
```